# Adding class to each item after third with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a very simple HTML which is as follow:

```
<ul class="my_class">
<li>List</li>
<li>List</li>
<li>List</li>
<li>List</li>
<li>List</li>
</ul>
```

What I am trying to acheave is to add a class "fred" to every single `<li>` that is appending after 3rd `<li>`.

This small function is adding it to hhe first 3 items :

```
$('ul.my_class li:lt(3)').addClass('fred');
```

Thank you all for your help in advance!

Dom

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following script:

```
$('ul.my_class li:nth-child(1n+4)').addClass('fred');
```

You can test the result here: http://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/

**Update:** Even after getting a few upvotes, I do prefer [Schiavini's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9314506/104435). It's more readable and more semantically correct

Comment: Very nice. The index can be simplified to just `n+4`.

Answer (score 5):

This will do:

```
$('ul.my_class li:gt(2)').addClass('fred');
```

Comment: nice and clean, but shouldn't it be `gt(2)` since this is a zero-based selector, and he's wanting everything after the 3rd `li`, which is index=2?

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**

The following will add `'fred'` to all `<li>` elements after the third:

```
$('ul.my_class li:gt(2)').addClass('fred');​
```

**[Working Solution Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mXNX7/2/)**

**Explanation of your existing code:**

```
$('ul.my_class li:lt(3)').addClass('fred');​
```

will add `'fred'` to all `<li>` elements from the first to the third.

**[Example of your existing code](http://jsfiddle.net/mXNX7/1/)**

Comment: That's backwards.  _"...every single `<li>` that is appending **after** 3rd"_

Comment: He's asking to affect everything *after* the 3rd `li`.

Comment: @Sparky672 - I just reworded it, does it make better sense now?

Comment: @Sparky672 - I noticed it was in his question. So I was explaining what his code did, then provided the answer that he was looking for.

Comment: Yes, I see now.  Just one small issue... you say it applies to _"all"_ `li` elements _"INCLUDING the 3rd"_.  Doesn't it just apply to elements 0, 1, & 2 which is not "all"?  See http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Use gt (greater than) instead of lt (less than), and start from 2 because the index is zero-based:

```
$('ul.my_class li:gt(2)').addClass('fred');
```

Here are the official specs:
[:gt() Selector – jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

Answer (score -1):

Use the following selector:
`UL.my_class > LI + LI + LI + LI`

`:gt()` selector is nonstandard and therefore is **much slower** in browsers with native `querySelectorAll()` support (all current browsers have this support). `:gt()` selector page on api.jquery.com has [note](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/#notes-0) about that.

[`:nth-child()`](http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child) is not supported by IE8 that have support for `querySelectorAll()` and therefore `:nth-child()` in IE8 is potentially slower too.

Comment: The problem with this is, what if there are more `<li>`'s than in the example? This only works for one specific case, and most examples given by posters in SO are just examples, not actuals.

Comment: It solves exactly what user wants: to select all `LI` items after third one (take into account that first `LI` in selector has no `:first-child` after it).

Comment: Yes, I understand. I used to make these types of arguments too. But what if there are 10 `li` elements? The solution needs to be extensible.

Comment: Again: it selects _all_ LI elements after third one _regardless_ of how many `LI`s are inside current list. You probably should learn more about adjacent-sibling combinator.

Comment: Ah, you're correct. I'm sorry for mis-reading. I don't have a downvote to retract, so I'll give you an upvote. Thanks for your explanation.